# Laravel redirect to intended with POST

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.5 and trying to achieve the following scenario:
The user tries to submit a form with `POST`, but if not logged in, I show the login screen.

My problem is that after the login I use `return redirect()->intended('dashboard');` to continue the user flow that I interrupted. But the redirect turns the request to `GET`.

Is there any reasonable way to store the data from my initial form before facing the login screen, so I can restore it after being redirected after the login?

Comment: why not put the post data in to a session?  crude non laravel example `$_SESSION['posted']=$_POST;`

Comment: The problem is when to put it in the session. The controller I am posting the data to required the user to be logged in, so once I reach the place to keep the data, it is already lost.

Comment: Check to make sure the user is logged in before you ever display the form.  A redirect back to the form should not change how the form handles its form submission.

Comment: @Joseph_J, thanks for the suggestion. It completely makes sense. My problem is that this form is part of the root page and it would not be very usable for my users.

Comment: What about saving the data in the browser's LocalStorage? Then when the user goes back, if the data exists in LocalStorage, populate the form fields with those values.

Answer (score 0):

In ur middleware do this

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    return $next($request);
}else if (!Auth::check() ){
    $url = Request()->path();
    Session::put('loginRedirect', $url);
    return redirect('/login');
}
```

In LoginController

```
if(Session::get('loginRedirect')){
    $url = Session::get('loginRedirect');
    Session::forget('loginRedirect');
    return Redirect::intended(url($url));
}
return Redirect::intended(route('user.get_home'));
```

Comment: Let me know how have u used this ?

Comment: In version 5.5?